# ISTIO Ingress Gateway logs

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, dremio

We have set up Istio, and we are using ISTIO ingress gateway for inbound traffic. We have set up TLS for TCP port. Sample code can be found [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/).

We also enabled logs by following [this ISTIO guide](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/)

We tested the TLS connection using openssl and it works fine.

However, when we try to connect from an application, the TLS negotiation fails. I have provided more details with wireshark [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12019/tls-handshake-failure)

We would like to get logs from ISTIO on the TLS negotiation ... and find why it fails.

Istio Gateway YAML

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: dremio-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
    hosts:
    - testdomain.net
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: testdomain-credentials
    hosts:
    - testdomain.net
  - port:
      number: 31020
      name: odbc-dremio-tls
      protocol: tls
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      minProtocolVersion: TLSV1_0
      maxProtocolVersion: TLSV1_3
      credentialName: testdomain-credentials
    hosts:
    - testdomain.net
```

Virtual Service

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: dremio
spec:
  hosts:
  - testdomain.net
  gateways:
  - dremio-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - port: 443
    - port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: dremio-client
        port:
          number: 9047
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 31020
    route:
    - destination:
        host: dremio-client
        port:
          number: 31010
```

Partial Config Dump

```
{
     "name": "0.0.0.0_31020",
     "active_state": {
      "version_info": "2020-07-21T12:11:49Z/9",
      "listener": {
       "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.api.v2.Listener",
       "name": "0.0.0.0_31020",
       "address": {
        "socket_address": {
         "address": "0.0.0.0",
         "port_value": 31020
        }
       },
       "filter_chains": [
        {
         "filter_chain_match": {
          "server_names": [
           "testdomain.net"
          ]
         },
         "filters": [
          {
           "name": "istio.stats",
           "typed_config": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/udpa.type.v1.TypedStruct",
            "type_url": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.wasm.v3.Wasm",
            "value": {
             "config": {
              "root_id": "stats_outbound",
              "vm_config": {
               "vm_id": "tcp_stats_outbound",
               "runtime": "envoy.wasm.runtime.null",
               "code": {
                "local": {
                 "inline_string": "envoy.wasm.stats"
                }
               }
              },
              "configuration": "{\n  \"debug\": \"false\",\n  \"stat_prefix\": \"istio\"\n}\n"
             }
            }
           }
          },
          {
           "name": "envoy.tcp_proxy",
           "typed_config": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.tcp_proxy.v2.TcpProxy",
            "stat_prefix": "outbound|31010||dremio-client.dremio.svc.cluster.local",
            "cluster": "outbound|31010||dremio-client.dremio.svc.cluster.local",
            "access_log": [
             {
              "name": "envoy.file_access_log",
              "typed_config": {
               "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.accesslog.v2.FileAccessLog",
               "path": "/dev/stdout",
               "format": "[%START_TIME%] \"%REQ(:METHOD)% %REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)% %PROTOCOL%\" %RESPONSE_CODE% %RESPONSE_FLAGS% \"%DYNAMIC_METADATA(istio.mixer:status)%\" \"%UPSTREAM_TRANSPORT_FAILURE_REASON%\" %BYTES_RECEIVED% %BYTES_SENT% %DURATION% %RESP(X-ENVOY-UPSTREAM-SERVICE-TIME)% \"%REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)%\" \"%REQ(USER-AGENT)%\" \"%REQ(X-REQUEST-ID)%\" \"%REQ(:AUTHORITY)%\" \"%UPSTREAM_HOST%\" %UPSTREAM_CLUSTER% %UPSTREAM_LOCAL_ADDRESS% %DOWNSTREAM_LOCAL_ADDRESS% %DOWNSTREAM_REMOTE_ADDRESS% %REQUESTED_SERVER_NAME% %ROUTE_NAME%\n"
              }
             }
            ]
           }
          }
         ],
         "transport_socket": {
          "name": "envoy.transport_sockets.tls",
          "typed_config": {
           "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.api.v2.auth.DownstreamTlsContext",
           "common_tls_context": {
            "tls_params": {
             "tls_minimum_protocol_version": "TLSv1_0",
             "tls_maximum_protocol_version": "TLSv1_3"
            },
            "alpn_protocols": [
             "h2",
             "http/1.1"
            ],
            "tls_certificate_sds_secret_configs": [
             {
              "name": "testdomain-credentials",
              "sds_config": {
               "api_config_source": {
                "api_type": "GRPC",
                "grpc_services": [
                 {
                  "google_grpc": {
                   "target_uri": "unix:/var/run/ingress_gateway/sds",
                   "stat_prefix": "sdsstat"
                  }
                 }
                ]
               }
              }
             }
            ]
           },
           "require_client_certificate": false
          }
         }
        }
       ],
       "listener_filters": [
        {
         "name": "envoy.listener.tls_inspector",
         "typed_config": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.listener.tls_inspector.v2.TlsInspector"
         }
        }
       ],
       "traffic_direction": "OUTBOUND"
      },
      "last_updated": "2020-07-21T12:11:50.303Z"
     }
    }
```

By enabling tracing on Envoy conn_handler, We can see the following message:

> closing connection: no matching filter chain found

Comment: I would say you should check ingress gateway/istiod logs with `kubectl logs`, additionally you can exec into  ingress gateway and dump your config with `curl 0:15000/config_dump`. `However, when we try to connect from an application, the TLS negotiation fails` can you add output from `curl -v`? Can you add  your gateway, virtual service and destination rule yamls?

Comment: @jt97 - Gateway & Virtual Service Yaml are provided above. kubectl logs on istiod and ingress gateway dont provide any logs about the tls negotiation. curl -v don't provide much as this is not http, but TCP only. The Application is an ODBC driver (Dremio ODBC Driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the message of no matching filter chain, I found the filter chain for the port 31020 with the domain that I have provided in my Gateway config. It looks like while connecting my application(ODBC), the host was not being provided.

The solution is simply to replace the host domain by '*'

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: dremio-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
    hosts:
    - testdomain.net
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: testdomain-credentials
    hosts:
    - testdomain.net
  - port:
      number: 31020
      name: odbc-dremio-tls
      protocol: tls
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      minProtocolVersion: TLSV1_0
      maxProtocolVersion: TLSV1_3
      credentialName: testdomain-credentials
    hosts:
    - '*'
```